# "not declared in scope" error in a header file with templates

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, compiler-errors, boost-function

So, I create a header file that has the following:

```
namespace A
{

template<int a>
void foo(...)
{
    //This throws a "test was not declared in this scope" error:
    boost::function< bool (int, int)> t = test<a>; 
}

template<int a>
bool test(int c, int d)
{
    //Do stuff;
}
}
```

However, the error is thrown on compilation, and I don't know why.  test is obviously in scope.

replacing `test<a>` with `boost:ref(test<a>)` or `&test<a>` still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a forward declaration of `test`, just like you would for any other function.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the obvious... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to atleast *declare* something before you can use it. The compiler doesn't know it actually exists before that.

```
namespace A
{

template<int a>
bool test(int c, int d);

template<int a>
void foo(...)
{
    //This throws a "test was not declared in this scope" error:
    boost::function< bool (int, int)> t = test<a>; 
}

template<int a>
bool test(int c, int d)
{
    //Do stuff;
}
}
```

Comment: Expanding on this answer, the statement at lines 4-5 is the **forward declaration** of `test`, i.e. a preliminary **declaration** for the actual **definition** that is stated later, at lines 14-18.